# Cannot click hidden button by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf, jsf-1.2

```
function openEditDialog(){
    window.showModalDialog('/atmew/pages/asset/searchInclude/assetEdit.mew');
    document.getElementById('reData').click();
    alert('after rerender');
}
```

then there is a button:

```
<a4j:commandLink id="edit" action="#{searchController.openAssetEdit}" 
    oncomplete="openEditDialog()" immediate="true" ajaxSingle="true">
    <h:graphicImage url="/images/edit_icon.png" </h:graphicImage>
    <f:param name="arId" id="arId" value="#{vo.assetReceiving.id}"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

The Other button

```
<a4j:commandButton id="reData" reRender="data_grid" style="visibility: hidden;" onclick="javascript:alert('rerender clicked');"></a4j:commandButton>
```

the reData button does not get clicked. The console of IE does not show any message. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Your other button doesn't need the javascript: part inside its onclick attribute that's only when the javascript is inside a href attribute.

Comment: what do you mean `is it ok?` what is the question?

Comment: why are you trying to click a hidden element? o-o

Comment: @user1090190: the particular button will re-render (reload) a specific portion in the HTML structure identified by `data_grid` by ajax.

Comment: @BalusC Interesting. Is there a less hacky way to interface to it, or are you forced to use `click`?

Comment: @user1090190: Depends on OP's concrete functional requirement which is nowhere stated in the question.

Comment: @BalusC sure, only asking out of curiosity. I've never worked with jsf before.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the JSF-generated HTML element ID, not the JSF component ID.

Open the page in browser, rightclick and *View Source* and locate the JSF-generated HTML `<input type="submit">` element of the `<a4j:commandButton>` in the HTML source. It'll look like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="someFormId:reData" ... />
```

You need to use exactly that ID in JavaScript, simply because JavaScript works on the HTML DOM tree, not on the JSF component tree.

```
document.getElementById('someFormId:reData').click();
```

Further you'd better be using `<a4j:commandLink>` instead of `<a4j:commandButton>` in order to get `click()` to work.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. I must be tired & out of brains to have used jsp ID. No more comments for a question that got 2 -ve ratings. :(

Comment: I thought I my approach was wrong, but its working after ID correction. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to call the onclick via `document.getElementById("my-id").click()`? At least doing this in Chrome shows me the error "has no method 'click'". Or this possible when using jsf? (EDIT: sorry, might be a stupid question, but I never used jsf)

I think the only reliable way to artificially create a click event on a native node is to do that via browser mechanisms:

```
function doEvent(element, eventType, event) {
  // modern browsers
  if (document.createEvent) {
    event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    event.initMouseEvent(eventType, true, true, element.ownerDocument.defaultView,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);

  // older browsers (IE6/7 for exmaple)
  } else if (element.fireEvent) {
    element.fireEvent("on"+eventType);
  }
}

doEvent(document.getElementById("my-id"), "click");
```

regarding the ID consider the answer of [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)